# Joomla 3+ strange session storage behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, session, joomla, joomla3.0

As everyone knows, Joomla support different types of session handler (file, database, none, memcached etc). When users set up session handler to "none" we expect that there will be no more queries to database to handle session data.

But when you set session handler to "none", you will see that your `#__session` still has data and there are queries to this table on every page hit.

In `/libraries/cms/application/cms.php` you can see function `checkSession()`.

```
/**
* Checks the user session.
*
* If the session record doesn't exist, initialise it.
* If session is new, create session variables
*
* @return  void
*
* @since   3.2
*/
```

In this function you can see database queries which are uses to select and insert to #__session table.

If you simple add "return;" statement site will be still full functional because of session handler setted to "none".

Why do we need this function? Why this function don't check what type of session handler do we use? Is this behavior is necessary or my solution with adding return in beginning of function is normal?

Comment: If you don't have a session, your users would have to login again on every page they visit. Your site will become extremely slow because all the information stored in the session would have to be recreated (not just reread) on every page.  If you dump out the session object you will see that it is a lot of information. Sessions are how PHP becomes sort of stateful. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science).  "None" in  this case is a fallback to minimal. It's not ideal, the package is pretty old, but you will always need sessions.

Comment: No, if you set session handler to "none", your session data will be stored in file handler. You can check this in /libraries/joomla/session/storage/none.

Comment: If you look in JApplicationCMS::loadSession you will see this comment:  ` // TODO: At some point we need to get away from having session data always in the db.
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();`
 Bascially the CMS application is built around it having a record in te db no matter what. This is pretty old code, no one likes it, but it's big job to disentangle it. Also the CMS historically has has lots of issues with users who can't write files.

Comment: Having same problem, looks like not yet fixed in latest version of Joomla.

Comment: @Elin I realize this is 4 years old, but I'm facing the same issue, and I can't find JApplicationCMS class source code on Github. Can you please post a link to it? Maybe it was renamed meanwhile or the problem was fixed?

Comment: I'd recommend asking about this on the dedicated Joomla Stack Exchange site [joomla.se].  If you get a good answer there it would be great to post a link here.